# Should I upgrade Apache Cassandra?

Tags: database, cassandra, upgrade

My company is currently using Cassandra version 2.1.8.

As of right now, there exist a version 3.7

Is there some way to know if I should update without going through all lines in the changelog? Is 2.1.8 a fine, stable version, or is it horribly outdated, and should be upgraded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As this isn't really "about programming" it's probably off-topic, but I'll answer because I know you won't get an answer on a different Stack Exchange site.*

I wouldn't consider 2.1.8 horribly out-dated.  There are places out there still running on much, much older versions than that.

Prior to 3.0, features are usually added in major point releases (2.0, 2.1, 2.2, etc...).  Minor releases like 2.1.14 are used for fixing bugs, so upgrading to the latest minor release is A) low risk and B) probably in your best interest.

Even though DataStax has now [released a DSE version containing Cassandra 3.0 at its core](http://www.datastax.com/2016/06/introducing-datastax-enterprise-5-0), I would still caution you against upgrading to 3.x.  3.x involved a major rewrite of the underlying storage engine.  It does have a lot of new features, but I'd recommend being patient while some of the [3.x JIRA tickets](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12053?jql=project%20%3D%20CASSANDRA%20AND%20%22Reproduced%20In%22%20in%20(3.0.7%2C%203.7%2C%203.0.6%2C%203.6%2C%203.5%2C%203.4%2C%203.3%2C%203.2.1%2C%203.2%2C%203.1.1%2C%203.1%2C%203.0.5%2C%203.0.4%2C%203.0.3%2C%203.0.2%2C%203.0.1%2C%203.0.0)) settle down a little bit.

Comment: Hi,
We are planning to upgrade from 2.1.16 to 3.0.15. But I see a major open ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13900. So we are a bit confused about whether to go ahead or not.

Please give your opinion on that.

Comment: @Laxmikant I have built a few new clusters running 3.10 and 3.11.  I haven't seen the issue described in CASSANDRA-13900, so it might be limited to the 3.0.x line.  3.11.1 fixed a few major bugs, so I'd say that one should be pretty stable.

Comment: Hi Aaron, Thanks a lot for the reply. We are also in dilemma to either chose 3.11.1 or 3.0.15. I can see a major ticket related to memory leak is opened for 3.11.1 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13929 , this ticket is stopping us to chose 3.11.1 . What do you think about this ?

Answer (score 1):

the #cassandra irc channel greeting says:

> Topic: cassandra.apache.org |  Tick-Tock: 3.7
>   | Current: 2.2.6 | Next: 3.0.7
>   | oldstable: 2.1.14

So 2.1.8 isn't that old. Don't pay attention to the Tick-Tock versions - they're pretty much the bleeding edge version. (Datastax Enterprise 5.0)[http://www.datastax.com/2016/06/introducing-datastax-enterprise-5-0] was released yesterday and it contains cassandra 3.0.something